# Impersonate with gwendall-impersonate

Tags: meteor

```
errorClass {error: 403, reason: "Permission denied. You need to be an admin to impersonate users.", details: undefined, message: "Permission denied. You need to be an admin to impersonate users. [403]", errorType: "Meteor.Error"}
details
:
undefined
error
:
403
errorType
:
"Meteor.Error"
message
:
"Permission denied. You need to be an admin to impersonate users. [403]"
reason
:
"Permission denied. You need to be an admin to impersonate users."
stack
:
(...)
get stack
:
get stack()
set stack
:
set stack()
__proto__
:
Error
```

I'm trying to impersonate the package Gwendal-impersonate but I get that error I think is for the package alanning-role

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the docs (https://github.com/gwendall/meteor-impersonate#server-methods), `alanning:roles` package is used to check if the user should be permitted to impersonate or not.

To fix this you can do something like: `Roles.addUsersToRoles(myUserId, ['admins'])` from the meteor shell.